# Kill process by name in Sublime Text 2

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Is there a cross-platform way to kill processes by their name with a sublime text plugin? I was looking at psutil, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940858/kill-process-by-name-in-python), but it seems that isn't available in sublime texts runtime.

I've been looking at exec.py, but it doesn't seem to expose the processes it creates. If I could get a hook on those created processes (and kill those), that'd work just as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just pulling in all of exec.py and making that work as I wanted to.