# Stopping a Process in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen, os.system

I am running a program that I would like to have stopped when a certain button is pushed.

I was thinking of running the process in the background so that the button can be pressed any time during the process and it would stop it.

I read stuff on subprocess from the documentation, but me being a beginner I have no idea how to use it, any help is appreciated.

```
def put(command):
        os.system(command)

        if direct == "":
            time.sleep(.5)
            arg1 = put("sudo ffmpeg -i \"" + q3 + "\" -f s16le -ar 22.05k -ac 1 - | sudo ./pifm - " + str(freq)) 
            subprocess.Popen(arg1)
            while True:
                if RPIO.input(25) == GPIO.LOW: #if button is pushed, kill process (arg1)
                    Popen.terminate()
```

Comment: Are you trying to have a python program kill other processes, or have it kill itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kill process by name in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940858/kill-process-by-name-in-python)

Comment: @aruisdante I am trying to kill the arg1 command that runs, it takes a while to run it, and I want to be able to stop it when I press the button.  Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep control on your subprocess, you'd better use the `subprocess` module. If you create it via `Popen`, you will be able to stop it via the `kill()` or `terminate()` methods.

Example

```
import subprocess
# ...
sub = subprocess.Popen(command)
# ...
sub.kill()
```

And you are sure you are killing your own child, even if there are numerous `command` running simutaneously

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to call terminate on *instance* od Popen:

```
if direct == "":
    time.sleep(.5)
    arg1 = put("sudo ffmpeg -i \"" + q3 + "\" -f s16le -ar 22.05k -ac 1 - | sudo ./pifm - " + str(freq)) 
    myproc = subprocess.Popen(arg1)
    while True:
        if RPIO.input(25) == GPIO.LOW: #if button is pushed, kill process (arg1)
            myproc.terminate()
```