# python check_output fails with exit status 1 but Popen works for same command

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Command framed to identify if Xcode is running on Mac: `cmd = "ps -ax | grep -v grep | grep Xcode"`

If Xcode is not running, then above command works well with `Popen` method of `subprocess` module, but raises a `CalledProcessError` with `check_output` method. I tried to inspect the `stderr` through the following code, but failed to get appropriate information to understand the reason.

```
from subprocess import check_output, STDOUT, CalledProcessError

psCmd = "ps -ax | grep -v grep | grep Xcode"
o = None
try:
    o = check_output(psCmd, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
except CalledProcessError as ex:
    print 'Error:', ex, o
```

Exception message is as follows:

`Error: Command 'ps -ax | grep -v grep | grep Xcode' returned non-zero exit status 1 None`

Question: Why the above command works with Popen, but fails with check_output ?

Note: Command works well with both approach, if Xcode is running.

Comment: You're much better off doing the `grep` processing in Python itself anyway.

Comment: Even if I process the output in python, I have to use `subprocess` module. So I think it's a good way to get all the work done at `bash` end.

Comment: related: [Kill process by name in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2940858/4279)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`check_output()` works as expected. Here's its simplified implementation in terms of `Popen()`:

```
def check_output(cmd):
    process = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE)
    output = process.communicate()[0]
    if process.returncode != 0:
        raise CalledProcessError(process.returncode, cmd, output=output)
    return output
```

`grep` returns `1` if it hasn't found anything i.e., you should expect the exception if Xcode is not running.

Note: as the implementation shows, you can get the output even if the exception occurs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_output, STDOUT, CalledProcessError

cmd = "ps -ax | grep -v grep | grep Xcode"
try:
    o = check_output(cmd, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
    returncode = 0
except CalledProcessError as ex:
    o = ex.output
    returncode = ex.returncode
    if returncode != 1: # some other error happened
        raise
```

You could probably use `pgrep -a Xcode` command instead (note: starts with `p`) or use `psutil` module for a portable code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import psutil # $ pip install psutil

print([p.as_dict() for p in psutil.process_iter() if 'Xcode' in p.name()])
```

Comment: I understood now, why check_output behaves as it behaves. Checking for return code is cool. I'll use your idea with errno. Some **doubts**: _1._ Why do we have to init `returncode` in `try` block with value 0? _2_. Can't we compare `ex.returncode` directly with value 1 in `if` condition? Does it serve some purpose, which I have not understood yet.

Comment: `returncode` is set inside try/except in order to 1. show you that it is always zero if `check_output()` hasn't raised an exception 2. both branches (with and without the exception) set both variables: you can use `o` and `returncode` after the code regardless of whether Xcode is running or not.

Answer (score 2):

From the Python docs: "If the return code was non-zero it raises a CalledProcessError.". That's what happens to you when Xcode isn't running; the final `grep Xcode` exits with a non-zero status because `grep` couldn't find the string `Xcode` that you're looking for. Hence, `check_output()` will raise the exception.

BTW, I found this on [the Python subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: I don't see so. If I run this command in terminal without Xcode launched and check the errno variable, it still hold the value 0. To check errno I used echo "$?".

Comment: Ummm... when I try `ps -aef | grep -v grep | grep Xcode ; echo $?`, I get as output: `1`

Comment: @DeepakrajHR you mean even if Xcode is not launched your grep command is finding it? The Error message which you have displayed `Error: Command 'ps -ax | grep -v grep | grep Xcode' returned non-zero exit status 1 None` is the output of your python script because you have handled the exception in your code

Comment: Terminal output when Xcode isn't running

`$ ps -ax | grep -v grep | grep Xcode
$ echo "$?"
0
$`

Terminal output if Xcode is running
`$ ps -ax | grep -v grep | grep Xcode
13784 ??         0:02.34 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
$ echo "$?"
0
$`

So my point is, I don't think that error code 1 is coming from here in here. I'm missing something else.

Comment: I just made sure of it :-)

Comment: Guys my bad. I was using command as `echo "$?"` rather than `echo $?`. I too got error code 1.

Comment: That should not matter, the quotes are harmless (and in fact good form, especially if you are not sure of quoting).

Answer (score 1):

If your grep command `grep Xcode` returns no result then the `returncode` of the command will be non-zero, that's why `check_output` is calling `CalledProcessError`, which is what you are seeing in the output of `print` command

To get the output of your command be it error or success use following piece of code:-

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import check_output, STDOUT, CalledProcessError

psCmd = "ps -aef | grep -v grep | grep Xcode"
o = None
o = check_output(psCmd+";exit 0", stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
```

check_output will only show you the output of the command if it's return code is `0` else it calls an exception.

Comment: Please see my comment on Karel Kubat's answer

Comment: That's a nice idea as shown in [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). But why I'm getting error code as 1 from python script and 0 from terminal. Anyway now I'm using Popen to solve the problem. But the question still remains :-(

Comment: I got my answer. Now I'm using this way. But I'm wondering now, what if the command fails for some other unknown reason. I think that too will bypass because of `exit 0`. Is there a way to catch those exceptions.

Comment: This is not a sane answer.  Don't use `check_output` if you don't want to check the result code from the command.

Comment: `exit 0` is bad. It ignores errors. You can [get the output even if an exception happens](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28689969/4279).

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `check_output` is to make sure that the command you ran completed successfully.  It's *supposed* to fail if `grep Xcode` does not return success.

What you want would be a lot simpler with the searching in Python, anyway.

```
output = check_output(['ps', '-ax'], shell=False)
if 'Xcode' in output:
    print('Xcode appears to be running')
```

This has the additional (very minor) benefit over the shell version that it actually fails if `ps` fails for some reason.  The shell would simply ignore the exit code of `ps` when it's not at the end of a pipeline.