# Close folders with python-Code doen't work

Tags: python, directory

I work with python 2.7.8 and i use this code to close all open applications:

```
import os,subprocess

os.system('taskkill /im chrome.exe')
os.system('taskkill /im POWERPNT.exe')
os.system('taskkill /im OUTLOOK.exe')
os.system('taskkill /im WINWORD.exe')
os.system('taskkill /im ArcMap.exe')
os.system('taskkill /im acadlt.exe')
os.system('taskkill /im EXCEL.exe')
os.system('taskkill /im AcroBat.exe')
os.system('taskkill /im wmplayer.exe')
subprocess.call('nircmd.exe win close class "CabinetWClass"' , shell=True)
```

I succeed to close all applications except OUTLOOK and all the open folder of the windows 7 Professional

Comment: The Same code to close outlook is working fine with me !!

Comment: The open folders are instances of explorer.exe

Answer (score -1):

Try restart explorer.exe to close open folders.

```
os.system('taskkill /im explorer.exe')
os.system('explorer.exe')
```

Try **f** (force) parameter to force Outlook to close.

```
os.system('taskkill /f /im OUTLOOK.exe')
```

Also you can try this; https://stackoverflow.com/a/4230226/4471283

Comment: This will open the shut down dialouge box i guess !!

Comment: for me it does open a shutdown dialog box instead of closing the opened explorer instance !!

Comment: Umut Çağdaş Coşkun, now it close the outlook-thanks, but all window folders doesn't closed :-(

Comment: What do you mean with "all", does closing some folders or no one? Maybe you can try to add **/f** parameter like this `taskkill /f /im explorer.exe`

Comment: i mean all for other applications except the folders. i try to add  taskkill /f /im explorer.exe but then the computer crashed