# Fastest Way to Quit Subprocess in Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, subprocess

When starting a subprocess using `Popen` and later trying to end it using `terminate`, it can take over 10 seconds before the subprocess disappears from Windows Task Manager.

```
p = subprocess.Popen('foo.exe')
while True:
    ...    
    if quitProcess:
        p.terminate()
```

**Question:** Is there a quicker way to quit the subprocess, ideally within a second?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940858/kill-process-by-name-in-python

Comment: What makes you think that it is the killing that is slow instead of the Task Manager?

Comment: @displayname: do you mean that `taskkill /f` (`/f` means "forcefully terminated")  should end the process sooner than `TerminateProcess()` used by `p.terminate()`?

Comment: From MSDN, <https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714(v=vs.85).aspx>: "The terminated process cannot exit until all pending I/O has been completed or canceled."  Could that be the problem?

Comment: Processes naturally take a while to kill