# Can we generate a Ctrl+c using a python script

Tags: python, audio

**I have this Python script that start a recording and won't stop until I hit Ctrl+c manually,
I'm looking for way to stop the recording by executing a Python script that generate a Ctrl+c.**

Comment: @TomMcLean I think OP wants to generate the press not catch it.

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem. If you control how this recording script is started (from a main.py), then you can possibly also kill it from this main.py. It doesn't have to be a Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the same python script you can just call sys.exit.
Otherwise, you can kill the process by its pid or name.
see [Kill process by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940858/kill-process-by-name)