# Python: how to avoid psutil.process_iter() 'AccessDenied' and other misc errors?

Tags: python, command-line, process, access-denied, psutil

In Python, why am I seeing `psutil.AccessDenied` errors/exceptions when iterating through my processes (which works just fine) and printing their command lines via `psutil.cmdline()` (which, frustratingly experiences the aforementioned Exception for the exact same process, where `psutil.name()` works fine), as per the following code snippet?

```
import psutil
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    print (proc.name())    # seems to consistently work
    print (proc.cmdline()) # sometimes generates Exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Python (or at least my python v3.11.2, macOS v12.6.3 system) lets you *iterate* through *all* the OS/system's processes, but prevents you from reading the *cmdline* of all the processes, even if it lets you read the "base name" of the process of cmdline-problematic processes. [More details](https://www.florianreinhard.de/2022-02-28/accessdenied-in-psutil/).

So catch and bypass the exception:

```
    try:
        cmdline = proc.cmdline()
    except psutil.AccessDenied:
        continue
```

Full, working script (on my above macOS system):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import psutil, logging
log = logging.getLogger()

# psutil all-processes iteration:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/4230226/605356
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    # avoid erroring on proc.cmdline() + psutil.AccessDenied Exception,
    # even though proc.name() experiences no issue:
    # https://www.florianreinhard.de/2022-02-28/accessdenied-in-psutil/
    try:
        cmdline = proc.cmdline()
    except psutil.AccessDenied:
        continue
    except (psutil.ZombieProcess, psutil.NoSuchProcess):
        # these Exceptions also happen a lot on my
        # macOS v12.6.3, python v3.11.2 system
        continue
    except Exception as e: # optional and use with care;
                           # see https://stackoverflow.com/q/4990718/605356
        log.exception("something is wrong: " + ' '.join(cmdline))
        continue
    print('name = ' + proc.name())
    print('cmdl = ' + ' '.join(cmdline))
```

Comment: Yes, I encountered similar issues on Mac.